# RCWA for Non-Periodic Structure?

Tags: numerical-analysis, simulation, computational-physics

I have a quick question regarding Rigorous Coupled Wave Analysis (RCWA) for numerically solving problems (in optics). I am trying to simulate a device which is non-periodic in x, y directions (but is longitudinally homogenous in z-direction). Is this possible? If so, would you be able to point me toward some readings or materials (haven't been able to find any)? Thanks in advance!